# Htaccess RewriteRule - encoded slash not matched

Tags: .htaccess

I've got simple .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user_id=([0-9]+)/track/(.*)/save.js$ index.php?uid=$1&type=js&params=$2 [L]
```

My url's look like:
`mysite.com/user_id=12345/track/param1/param2/param3/save.js`

param1, param2, param3 are passed to save.js as 3 different params (exploded by '/' inside save.js).

I'd like to pass some params that have '/' in their value, so I'd have param1, param/2 and param3 
I've tried to encode this params so url would look like:

`mysite.com/user_id=12345/track/param1/param%2f2/param3/save.js`

Unfortunately rule is not matched, I got 404 from Apache.

EDIT:
Found reason why its not working for me:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Comment: What is that "user_id=12345" doing inside the url? Why not simply "mysite.com/12345/track/param1/param2/param3/save.js", since it should be clear that its the user id at that position? Or, if you _really_ require that marker, then make it "mysite.com/user/12345/track/param1/param2/param3/save.js"

Comment: Both of your URLs will be matched by given rule. Do you have other rules too?

Comment: @anubhava
I've commented all other rules to test this rule. Second url is still not matched.

Comment: It did match when I used it on my Apache

Comment: Try this if not working: `RewriteRule ^user_id=([0-9]+)/track/(.+?)/save\.js$ index.php?uid=$1&type=js&params=$2 [L,B]`

Comment: @anubhava
I've tride this rule:
`RewriteRule ^user_id=([0-9]+)/track/(.+?)/save\.js$ index.php?uid=$1&type=js&params=$2 [L,B]`
for address:
`mysite.com/user_id=14/track/param1/param2/param%2f3/save.js`
Result:
`Not Found The requested URL /user_id=14/track/param1/param2/param/3/save.js was not found on this server.`

My it's apache configuration issue?

Comment: What happens when you enter: `/user_id=14/track/param1/param2/param/3/save.js` in browser?

Comment: Url's without encoding work fine. As result I got 4 params: param1, param2, param, 3.

Comment: Ok, I found why it's not working for me:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes